# Auto Generate Alphanumeric(AANNNN) id's in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Want Auto Generate Alphanumeric(AANNNN)  id's in postgresql.
for eg=AA0001,AA9999,AB0001.
And the Order of value increment from right to left.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `SERIAL` column (auto-incrementing), then create a computed column with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  ID SERIAL,
  CharID varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      CHR(65 + ID / 260000) ||
      CHR(65 + MOD(ID / 10000, 26)) ||
      lpad(MOD(id, 260000)::text, 4, '0')
    ) STORED
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c6f0b5e63ee0aa172834409e5e9f854f)

It's simple arithmetic: uppercase letters begin at character `66`, and there are 26 of them. So the first two lines create those two, using integer division and modular division. Then use modular division again to get the final 4 digits.